# how to synchronize two databases of different servers?

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, mysql-workbench, mysql-gui-tools

I have two databases. One is on local server and the other is on a production server. I'm continuously working on the local server and after approval I want to update production server. Wih the current setup, I need to take dump or copy or export of database and then import into production database, every time. Is there any way of synchronization method in phpmyadmin for database on different server.

It is possible to synchronize a model in MySQL Workbench with a live database?

Other then this, how can I do this? I'm able to use queries, the command line and phpmyadmin itself.

Please specified any simple method.

Comment: Is there any free tool like sqlyog, heidisql etc or any method?

Comment: I got way of my solution. In SQLyog, there is synchronization tab. Sqlyog -> Powertools -> Database synchronize wizard. But i get some error, trying to resolve that.

Comment: **Definition mismatch for 'tinyint(1) unsigned zerofill' column in** 'abcd`' table.` I found this error. how can i solved this problem?

Comment: MySQL Workbench models are not the right tool for data synchronisation. Such models are all about meta data.

Comment: @MikeLischke : suggest any tool or tech?

Comment: As I suggested in my answer there's no GUI tool to do autamtic data sync. Replication (once set up) is the closest you can get for regular autmatic data sync. If you don't want that you have step back to manually taking backups and applying them manually to the target server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "synchronisation" feature you are looking for is called [**replication**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html). A replication can be set up between a master and a slave machine. It does not rely on a constant connection, but stores all changes on the master and replays all those changes on the slave once a connection is established.

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I checked your link. its very confusing for me. i searched on google. i got simple [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql). But is there any mysqli script, because i am not user friendly with cmd.